# Eclipse configuration to launch a Maven project with Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I'm starting a GWT project with web creator as following:

```
C:\>webAppCreator -noant -maven -overwrite -out MavenTest com.raphiki.MavenTest
```

It generates a Maven project's structure with an GWT Hello world project, I import this project in Eclipse as a *Maven project with existing sources*.

Then I enable Google Web Toolkit in my project, and I need to give a WAR path. I try with the `/src/main/webapp` which contains the entry point, but when I launch the app I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on Hello world's class's package.

See the following image which is the structure the WebAppCreator built:

[image]

Did I miss any configuration to do?

Answer (score 0):

See http://web.archive.org/web/20130619170526/https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

TL;DR: run `mvn package` (or `mvn war:exploded`), then run DevMode, choose `target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/` as webapp directory.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the webAppCreator because I haven't used it, but I have had good luck creating the Maven projects in Eclipse using the gwt-maven-plugin from codehause.

**Creating a Maven GWT Project Directy in Eclipse**

1. Open the new project wizard in Eclipse and filter on Maven Project.
2. Select the Maven Project and click next.
3. Enter the project location of your preference and click next.
4. Enter "gwt-" into the archetype filter and select the gwt-maven-plugin from codehaus. Click Next.
5. Enter your maven project details and a module value, then click Finish.

This will create a maven - gwt project for you in Eclipse. This comes with a sample application that you can use to make sure you can launch the application correctly.

**Running the Application Command Line**

1. Open command line.
2. Navigate to your project home.
3. Run the command "mvn clean package".
4. Run the command "mvn gwt:run"

This should get you up and running.  If you used the 2.7.0 gwt-maven-plugin this should run the application in super dev mode by default.

**Run the application in Eclipse**

1. As you have done, navigate to Properties > Google > Web Application and check "This project has a WAR directory".  The WAR directory using this plugin should be src/main/webapp.
2. Navigate to Properties > Google > Web Toolkit and check "This project has a WAR directory.  You may be able to specify the module here.  I am actually unable to do so, it may be specific to my Google Plugin for Eclipse or something environment specific...
3. Run As > Web Application.
4. If you had issues, as I have had, in step 2 then you will get an error `Missing required argument 'module[s]'`.  To fix this open up your run configuration (should have been auto created) and in the arguments tab add the package qualified name for your module at the end of the arguments, e.g. com.mycompany.abc.GwtSampleModule.  Do not add the ".gwt.xml" prefix.

   5. It's worth also checking that the HTML page referenced in your arguments is correct, I have also had issues with that.

The application should now be configured for Launch in Eclipse using this run configuration.  My verified environment is:

- Eclipse Luna (v4.4)
- Google Plugin for Eclipse (v3.8)
- GWT Maven Plugin (v2.7.0)